# Getting Custom Collection without some fields

Tags: magento-1.9, module, collection, custom, select

It is magento 1.9.4.0 and i need a array with some nodes. When i get the models collection with:

```
Mage::getModel('nstok/nstok')
                                   ->getCollection()
                                   ->toArray();
```

It returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [entity_id] => 1
            [stok_kodu] => 15201-1SI0001
            [stok_adi] => ETİK DEĞERLER EĞİTİM SETİ-1. SINIF (10 KİTAP+HDS)
            [barkod1] => 9786053836483
            [barkod2] => 9786053836483
            [barkod3] => 
            [ingisim] => TUBA BOZCAN
            [kdv_orani] => 0
            [satis_fiat1] => 37.00
            [satis_fiat2] => 33.33
            [satis_fiat3] => 27.78
            [satis_fiat4] => 0.00
            [kdvli_satisfiat1] => 37.00
            [kdvli_satisfiat2] => 33.33
            [kdvli_satisfiat3] => 27.78
            [kdvli_satisfiat4] => 0.00
            [alis_kdv_kodu] => 0
            [alis_fiat1] => 0.00
            [alis_fiat2] => 0.00
            [alis_fiat3] => 0.00
            [alis_fiat4] => 0.00
            [olcu_br1] => TAKIM
            [olcu_br2] => 
            [olcu_br3] => 
            [birim_agirlik] => 0.6200
            [en] => 16.5000
            [boy] => 23.5000
            [genislik] => 2.0000
            [satici_kodu] => 
            [uretici_kodu] => 0
            [grup_kodu] => HIKAYE
            [kod_1] => 185
            [kod_2] => 07
            [kod_3] => 99
            [kod_4] => 113
            [kod_5] => CE
            [kod1_adi] => Etik Değerler Eğitim Seti
            [kod2_adi] => Hikaye
            [kod3_adi] => Diğer
            [kod4_adi] => Hikaye %55
            [kod5_adi] => Çocuk Edebiyatı
            [azami_stok] => 0
            [asgari_stok] => 0
            [min_sip_miktar] => 0
            [temin_suresi] => 0
            [nakliye_tut] => 0.0000
            [max_iskonto] => 0.0000
            [onceki_kodu] => -EDES1
            [sonraki_kodu] => 
            [sonstokkodu] => 
            [birim_maliyet] => 0.0000
            [kull1n] => 160
            [kull2n] => 10
            [kull3n] => 2018
            [kull4n] => 0
            [kull5n] => 0
            [kull6n] => 2147483647
            [kull7n] => 0
            [kull8n] => 0
            [kull1s] => Damla Yayınevi
            [kull2s] => 1
            [kull3s] => 1
            [kull4s] => 0
            [kull5s] => 1
            [kull6s] => Kuşe
            [kull7s] => Türkçe
            [kull8s] => 5DB8
            [aciklama] => Çocuklar... Üzerlerine titrediğimiz, en değerli varlıklarımız...
Onları erdemli, yüksek ahlaklı, değerlerimizi bilen ve sahip çıkan bireyler olarak yetiştirmek herkesin ortak amacı. Bunun da en önemli aracı hikâyeler.    
İşte “Etik Değerler Eğitim Seti” buradan yola çıkarak hazırlandı. “Değerler Eğitimi” temel alınarak her hikâyede bir değer işlendi.
Her hikâyenin sonundaki “Etkinlikler”le verilmek istenilen değerin pekiştirilmesi sağlanmıştır.
            [stok_bakiye] => 3860
            [kayittarihi] => 2013-04-06 12:59:42
            [kayityapankul] => SPALANCI
            [duzeltmetarihi] => 2018-12-04 09:39:09
            [duzeltmeyapankul] => MYILGIN
            [kilit] => 
            [updated_at] => 2019-02-21 16:24:21
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [entity_id] => 2
            [stok_kodu] => 15201-3BO0002
            [stok_adi] => 3 BOYUTLU BOYAMALI AKTİVİTE STANDI KAMPANYASI (180 KİTAP)
            [barkod1] => 8697911211285
            [barkod2] => 8697911211285
            [barkod3] => 
            [ingisim] => Komisyon
            [kdv_orani] => 0
            [satis_fiat1] => 1527.00
            [satis_fiat2] => 1250.00
            [satis_fiat3] => 1500.00
            [satis_fiat4] => 0.00
            [kdvli_satisfiat1] => 1527.00
            [kdvli_satisfiat2] => 1250.00
            [kdvli_satisfiat3] => 1500.00
            [kdvli_satisfiat4] => 0.00
            [alis_kdv_kodu] => 0
            [alis_fiat1] => 0.00
            [alis_fiat2] => 0.00
            [alis_fiat3] => 0.00
            [alis_fiat4] => 0.00
            [olcu_br1] => TAKIM
            [olcu_br2] => 
            [olcu_br3] => 
            [birim_agirlik] => 0.0000
            [en] => 0.0000
            [boy] => 0.0000
            [genislik] => 0.0000
            [satici_kodu] => 
            [uretici_kodu] => 0
            [grup_kodu] => KULTUR
            [kod_1] => 996
            [kod_2] => 07
            [kod_3] => 27
            [kod_4] => 127
            [kod_5] => CE
            [kod1_adi] => Muhtelif Stand ve Koli Çeşitle
            [kod2_adi] => Hikaye
            [kod3_adi] => 3D Kitap
            [kod4_adi] => Stant Kampanyaları
            [kod5_adi] => Çocuk Edebiyatı
            [azami_stok] => 0
            [asgari_stok] => 0
            [min_sip_miktar] => 0
            [temin_suresi] => 0
            [nakliye_tut] => 0.0000
            [max_iskonto] => 0.0000
            [onceki_kodu] => -3BBSK
            [sonraki_kodu] => 
            [sonstokkodu] => 
            [birim_maliyet] => 0.0000
            [kull1n] => 0
            [kull2n] => 1
            [kull3n] => 2016
            [kull4n] => 0
            [kull5n] => 0
            [kull6n] => 2147483647
            [kull7n] => 0
            [kull8n] => 0
            [kull1s] => Damla Yayınevi
            [kull2s] => 1
            [kull3s] => 2-3-4
            [kull4s] => 0
            [kull5s] => 1
            [kull6s] => Kuşe
            [kull7s] => Türkçe
            [kull8s] => 
            [aciklama] => 
            [stok_bakiye] => -1
            [kayittarihi] => 2016-04-19 11:10:45
            [kayityapankul] => SKARABUL
            [duzeltmetarihi] => 2019-02-05 11:26:34
            [duzeltmeyapankul] => SKARABUL
            [kilit] => 
            [updated_at] => 2019-02-21 16:24:21
        )
```

But i need the array without the entity_id
How can i filter/exclude the collection for this basicly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot @HelgeB. It is only working if there is something to select. So i did so..

```
$nstokcollection = Mage::getModel('nstok/nstok')
->getCollection()
->addFieldToSelect(array
('stok_kodu','stok_adi','barkod1','barkod2','barkod3','ingisim','kdv_orani','satis_fiat1','satis_fiat2','satis_fiat3','satis_fiat4','kdvli_satisfiat1','kdvli_satisfiat2','kdvli_satisfiat3','kdvli_satisfiat4','alis_kdv_kodu','alis_fiat1','alis_fiat2','alis_fiat3','alis_fiat4','olcu_br1','olcu_br2','olcu_br3','birim_agirlik','en','boy','genislik','satici_kodu','uretici_kodu','grup_kodu','kod_1','kod_2','kod_3','kod_4','kod_5','kod1_adi','kod2_adi','kod3_adi','kod4_adi','kod5_adi','azami_stok','asgari_stok','min_sip_miktar','temin_suresi','nakliye_tut','max_iskonto','onceki_kodu','sonraki_kodu','sonstokkodu','birim_maliyet','kull1n','kull2n','kull3n','kull4n','kull5n','kull6n','kull7n','kull8n','kull1s','kull2s','kull3s','kull4s','kull5s','kull6s','kull7s','kull8s','aciklama','stok_bakiye','kayittarihi','kayityapankul','duzeltmetarihi','duzeltmeyapankul','kilit')
)

->removeFieldFromSelect('entity_id')
->toArray();
```

Then Result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [stok_kodu] => 15201-1SI0001
            [stok_adi] => ETİK DEĞERLER EĞİTİM SETİ-1. SINIF (10 KİTAP+HDS)
            [barkod1] => 9786053836483
            [barkod2] => 9786053836483
            [barkod3] => 
            [ingisim] => TUBA BOZCAN
            [kdv_orani] => 0
            [satis_fiat1] => 37.00
            [satis_fiat2] => 33.33
            [satis_fiat3] => 27.78
            [satis_fiat4] => 0.00
            [kdvli_satisfiat1] => 37.00
            [kdvli_satisfiat2] => 33.33
            [kdvli_satisfiat3] => 27.78
            [kdvli_satisfiat4] => 0.00
            [alis_kdv_kodu] => 0
            [alis_fiat1] => 0.00
            [alis_fiat2] => 0.00
            [alis_fiat3] => 0.00
            [alis_fiat4] => 0.00
            [olcu_br1] => TAKIM
            [olcu_br2] => 
            [olcu_br3] => 
            [birim_agirlik] => 0.6200
            [en] => 16.5000
            [boy] => 23.5000
            [genislik] => 2.0000
            [satici_kodu] => 
            [uretici_kodu] => 0
            [grup_kodu] => HIKAYE
            [kod_1] => 185
            [kod_2] => 07
            [kod_3] => 99
            [kod_4] => 113
            [kod_5] => CE
            [kod1_adi] => Etik Değerler Eğitim Seti
            [kod2_adi] => Hikaye
            [kod3_adi] => Diğer
            [kod4_adi] => Hikaye %55
            [kod5_adi] => Çocuk Edebiyatı
            [azami_stok] => 0
            [asgari_stok] => 0
            [min_sip_miktar] => 0
            [temin_suresi] => 0
            [nakliye_tut] => 0.0000
            [max_iskonto] => 0.0000
            [onceki_kodu] => -EDES1
            [sonraki_kodu] => 
            [sonstokkodu] => 
            [birim_maliyet] => 0.0000
            [kull1n] => 160
            [kull2n] => 10
            [kull3n] => 2018
            [kull4n] => 0
            [kull5n] => 0
            [kull6n] => 2147483647
            [kull7n] => 0
            [kull8n] => 0
            [kull1s] => Damla Yayınevi
            [kull2s] => 1
            [kull3s] => 1
            [kull4s] => 0
            [kull5s] => 1
            [kull6s] => Kuşe
            [kull7s] => Türkçe
            [kull8s] => 5DB8
            [aciklama] => Çocuklar... Üzerlerine titrediğimiz, en değerli varlıklarımız...
Onları erdemli, yüksek ahlaklı, değerlerimizi bilen ve sahip çıkan bireyler olarak yetiştirmek herkesin ortak amacı. Bunun da en önemli aracı hikâyeler.    
İşte “Etik Değerler Eğitim Seti” buradan yola çıkarak hazırlandı. “Değerler Eğitimi” temel alınarak her hikâyede bir değer işlendi.
Her hikâyenin sonundaki “Etkinlikler”le verilmek istenilen değerin pekiştirilmesi sağlanmıştır.
            [stok_bakiye] => 3860
            [kayittarihi] => 2013-04-06 12:59:42
            [kayityapankul] => SPALANCI
            [duzeltmetarihi] => 2018-12-04 09:39:09
            [duzeltmeyapankul] => MYILGIN
            [kilit] => 
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of the collection you are using, you can try to use `removeFieldFromSelect`

```
Mage::getModel('nstok/nstok')
->getCollection()
->removeFieldFromSelect('entity_id')
->toArray();
```

Otherwise - if the above approach does not work - you can just iterate thru the array and unset the field 'entity_id' in a foreach loop and that should give you what you need.